# I have a change() event that's not firing in IE 11 but works fine with Chrome and Edge. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

```
<script>
    // If the CountyId changes because the user selected a County from the DropDownList.
    $(function () {
        
        $("#RCE_CountyId").change(function () {
            alert("It works !");
            var countyId = $(this).val();

            $("#RCE_RouteId").empty();
            $("#RCE_RouteId").append("<option value=''>Select Route</option>");
            //var d1 = '?handler=RouteList&CountyId=' + countyId;
            //alert(d1);

            $.getJSON('?handler=RouteList&CountyId=' + countyId, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $("#RCE_RouteId").append('<option value=' + item.routeId + '>' + item.routeName + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? You're using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility) which is not supported by IE. Besides, please also provide the related html code to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: As above, `=>` is not supported in IE11 and you *will* be getting an error that you should have checked for.  https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions   If you're after *any* help, then it would be to suggest you stop supporting IE11.  MS have with final end-of-life Aug 21.

Comment: The you for your response.  I've never heard of arrow functions.  I will research it.  How could I convert the above into javascrip?.

Comment: Or even better, How do I convert the $.getJSON part?  I came up with a solution for the other lines.  Now I need to send the JSON result.

Comment: $.getJSON('?handler=RouteList&CountyId=' + countyId, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $("#RCE_RouteId").append('<option value=' + item.routeId + '>' + item.routeName + '</option>');
                });
            });

Comment: @Yu Zhou I appreciate the help you provided.  The Arrow Function was the cause of my problem as you mentioned.  Thank you for your help.  All I had to do in the above code was replace => with the word function.  Then pass my parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility) which is not supported by IE. Please replace the arrow function with the code below:

```
$.getJSON('?handler=RouteList&CountyId=' + countyId, function (data) {
    ...
});
```